# Parsing a text file to store into class objects and attributes

Tags: python, class, parsing, text, formatting

2 part question. How to parse text and save as class object/attributes and       best way to rewrite text from the classes in a specific format.

I'm wanting to parse through a text file and extract sections of text  and     create a class object and attributes. There will be several classes (Polygons,     space, zone, system, schedule) involved. In the original file each "Object" and it's "attributes" are separated by '..'.  An example of one is below.

```
"Office PSZ" = SYSTEM
    TYPE             = PSZ
    HEAT-SOURCE      = FURNACE
    FAN-SCHEDULE     = "HVAC Yr Schedule"
    COOLING-EIR      = 0.233207
    ..
```

I'd like to read this text and store into class objects.  So "Office PSZ"     would be of the HVACsystem or SYSTEM class, haven't decided.  'SYSTEM' would be a     class variable.  For this instance ("Office PSZ"), self.TYPE would be PSZ.      self.HEAT-SOURCE would equal FURNACE,etc.

I want to manipulate these objects based on their attributes.  The end result     though would be to write all the data that was manipulated back into a text file     with the original format.  End result for this instance may be.

```
   "Office PSZ" = SYSTEM 
    TYPE             = PSZ
    HEAT-SOURCE      = ELECTRIC
    FAN-SCHEDULE     = "Other Schedule"
    COOLING-EIR      = 0.200
     ..
```

Is there a way to print the attribute name/title (idk what to call it)? Because the attribute name (i.e. TYPE,HEAT-SOURCE) comes from the original file and it would be easier to not have to manually anticipate all of the attributes associated with every class.

I suppose I could create an array of all of the values on the left side of "=" and another array for the values on the right and loop through those as I'm writing/formatting a new text file.  But I'm not sure if that's a good way to go.

I'm still quite the amateur so I might be overreaching but any suggestions on how I should proceed?

Comment: It sounds like you want to use an object as a *container*, ie, as an organised place to store a collection of data. You seem to want a container which enables you to collect named items of data. If this is true then it might be easier to use a dictionary. You could say, `Office_PSZ = { 'TYPE': 'PSZ', 'HEAT-SOURCE': 'ELECTRIC', ...}` If you read the `dict` doc you'll find that you can add arbitrary items to a dictionary, access them individually as necessary, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Pyparsing makes it easy to write custom parsers for data like this, and gives back 
parsed data in a pyparsing data structure call ParseResults. ParseResults give you
access to your parsed values by position (like a list), by key (like a dict), or for
names that work as Python identifiers, by attribute (like an object).

I've simplfied my parsing of your data to pretty much just take every `key = value` line 
and build up a structure using the key strings as keys. The '..' lines work great
as terminators for each object.

A simple BNF for this might look like:

```
object ::= attribute+ end
attribute ::= key '=' value
key ::= word composed of letters 'A'..'Z' and '-', starting with 'A'..'Z', 
          or a quoted string
value ::= value_string | value_number | value_word
value_word ::= a string of non-whitespace characters
value_string ::= a string of any characters in '"' quotes
value_number ::= an integer or float numeric value
end ::= '..'
```

To implement a pyparsing parser, we work bottom up to define pyparsing sub-expressions.
Then we use Python '+' and '|' operators to assemble lower-level expressions to higher-level
ones:

```
import pyparsing as pp

END = pp.Suppress("..")
EQ = pp.Suppress('=')
```

pyparsing includes some predefined expressions for quoted strings and numerics;
the numerics will be automatically converted to ints or floats.

```
value_number = pp.pyparsing_common.number
value_string = pp.quotedString
value_word = pp.Word(pp.printables)
value = value_string | value_number | value_word
```

For our attribute key, we will use the two-argument form for Word. The first
argument is a string of allowable leading characters, and the second argument is a 
string of allowable body characters. If we just wrote `Word(alphas + '-'), then
our parser would accept '---' as a legal key.

```
key = pp.Word(pp.alphas, pp.alphas + '-') | pp.quotedString
```

An attribute definition is just a key, an '=' sign, and a value

```
attribute = key + EQ + value
```

Lastly we will use some of the more complex features of pyparsing. The simplest form
would just be "pp.OneOrMore(attribute) + END", but this would just give us back a 
pile of parsed tokens with no structure. The Group class structures the enclosed expressions
so that their results will be returned as a sub-list. We will catch every attribute as
its own sub-list using Group. Dict will apply some naming to the results, using 
the text from each key expression as the key for that group. Finally, the whole collection
of attributes will be Group'ed again, this time representing all the attributes for a
single object:

```
object_defn = pp.Group(pp.Dict(pp.OneOrMore(pp.Group(attribute)))) + END
```

To use this expression, we'll define our parser as:

```
parser = pp.OneOrMore(object_defn)
```

and parse the sample string using:

```
objs = parser.parseString(sample)
```

The `objs` variable we get back will be a pyparsing ParseResults, which will work like 
a list of the grouped object attributes. We can view just the parsed attributes as a list
of lists using asList():

```
for obj in objs:
    print(obj.asList())

[['"Office PSZ"', 'SYSTEM'], ['TYPE', 'PSZ'], ['HEAT-SOURCE', 'FURNACE'], 
 ['FAN-SCHEDULE', '"HVAC Yr Schedule"'], ['COOLING-EIR', 0.233207]]
```

If we had not used the Dict class, this would have all we would get, but since we
*did* use Dict, we can also see the attributes as a Python dict:

```
for obj in objs:
    print(obj.asDict())

{'COOLING-EIR': 0.233207, '"Office PSZ"': 'SYSTEM', 'TYPE': 'PSZ', 
 'FAN-SCHEDULE': '"HVAC Yr Schedule"', 'HEAT-SOURCE': 'FURNACE'}
```

We can even access named fields by name, if they work as Python identifiers. In your
sample, "TYPE" is the only legal identifier, so you can see how to print it here. There
is also a `dump()` method that will give the results in list form, followed by an
indented list of defined key pairs. (I've also shown how you can use list and dict
type access directly on the ParseResults object, without having to convert to list
or dict types):

```
for obj in objs:
    print(obj[0])
    print(obj['FAN-SCHEDULE'])
    print(obj.TYPE)
    print(obj.dump())

['"Office PSZ"', 'SYSTEM']
"HVAC Yr Schedule"
PSZ
[['"Office PSZ"', 'SYSTEM'], ['TYPE', 'PSZ'], ['HEAT-SOURCE', 'FURNACE'], 
 ['FAN-SCHEDULE', '"HVAC Yr Schedule"'], ['COOLING-EIR', 0.233207]]
- "Office PSZ": 'SYSTEM'
- COOLING-EIR: 0.233207
- FAN-SCHEDULE: '"HVAC Yr Schedule"'
- HEAT-SOURCE: 'FURNACE'
- TYPE: 'PSZ'
```

Here is the full parser code for you to work from:

```
import pyparsing as pp

END = pp.Suppress("..")
EQ = pp.Suppress('=')

value_number = pp.pyparsing_common.number
value_string = pp.quotedString
value_word = pp.Word(pp.printables)
value = value_string | value_number | value_word

key = pp.Word(pp.alphas, pp.alphas+"-") | pp.quotedString

attribute = key + EQ + value
object_defn = pp.Group(pp.Dict(pp.OneOrMore(pp.Group(attribute)))) + END

parser = pp.OneOrMore(object_defn)
objs = parser.parseString(sample)

for obj in objs:
    print(obj.asList())

for obj in objs:
    print(obj.asDict())

for obj in objs:
    print(obj[0])
    print(obj['FAN-SCHEDULE'])
    print(obj.TYPE)
    print(obj.dump())
```